# Manipulating with sibling DOM elements using angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, frontend

Let's say we have some div with 5 img elements. On hover, I want to change the class on all elements on the left.

```
<div id="stars">
     <img src="star.png" data-rating="1" ng-class="{rtHover: hover}" ng-mouseover="hoveredStars($event, 1)"/>
     <img src="star.png" data-rating="2" ng-class="{rtHover: hover}" ng-mouseover="hoveredStars($event, 2)"/>
     <img src="star.png" data-rating="3" ng-class="{rtHover: hover}" ng-mouseover="hoveredStars($event, 3)"/>
     <img src="star.png" data-rating="4" ng-class="{rtHover: hover}" ng-mouseover="hoveredStars($event, 4)"/>
     <img src="star.png" data-rating="5" ng-class="{rtHover: hover}" ng-mouseover="hoveredStars($event, 5)"/>
</div>
```

I want on hover to change "hover" variable on sibling elements, but don't know how to access them.

```
$scope.hoveredStars = function ($event, $selectedRating) {
    // Handling stars
}
```

Comment: Is the `hover` variable not defined on scope. You can directly do `$scope.hover=somevalue`. Not clear about the issue.

Comment: Issue is how to access first and second img element and change his class if I hover third img element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Accessing sibling scopes**

Access with `$$prevSibling` and `$$nextSibling` properties of your scopes.

**Playing with an integer**

Instead of having to access siblings scopes, manipulate an integer so that `ng-class` directive would become something like that:

```
ng-class="{ rtHover: 3 < myInteger }"
```

Then your `hoveredStar` would just have to set that integer.

**Performance concern**

Such a rate component, if used intensively in a same page, should not be an angular component since it generates a lot of digestions from the root scope.